# Android Studio error while adding dependency "Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)"

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit2

I was trying to add a dependency in build.gradle but it gives me some error

The dependency is

implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'

Android Studio error while adding dependency "Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)"